# how to add function to variable in php and then execute

Tags: php

i want to add the function getAddress(); to the variable namely as $fulltarget and then execute the result of the related variable having the getAddress() value too...!

the variable code is following..just make it correct please..that's it...

```
$fulltarget="getAddress(){$target}{$fullname}";
```

how to do that...i mean it will not echo the result of getAddress(); so please..tell me what's wrong with it...!

waiting for your reply...also please as i am new here..so avoid voting in negative...sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute a function inside a string. You need to concatenate it into the string

```
$fulltarget= getAddress() . "{$target}{$fullname}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add the result of calling the function? Then you can just [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) like the following

```
$fulltarget = getAddress()."{$target}{$fullname}";
```